# How to install pdo_mysql with my-php.ini in new ddev project?

Tags: php, ddev

I am trying to start a new project with the latest CiviCrm in the latest Drupal.  In composer.json I have "civicrm/civicrm-core": "^5.68" and "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.1".  Civicrm/cli-tools are installed and vendor/bin/cv gives a list of available commands.

Error: Undefined constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY on installing CiviCrm.

I attempt to install CiviCrm with these instructions

```
cv core:install --cms-base-url="https://d10.example.org" --db="mysql://database_user:database_pass@localhost:3306/civicrm_database"
```

but

```
Error: Undefined constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY in /home/nigel/Documents/ddev/d10-civi/web/core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/Connection.php on line 157 #0 /home/nigel/Documents/ddev/d10-civi/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(451): Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection::open()
```

Googling suggests I should install php extensions pdo and pdo_mysql. In .ddev/php/my-php.ini I have

```
[PHP]
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Then ddev restart.

But php -m shows that pdo is now installed but not pdo_mysql.

Can anyone see what I’m missing?

EDIT: NEXT DAY: SOLVED (this is so dumb)

I enabled CiviCrm Core in /admin/modules. Drupal, bless it, enabled Civi with no problem.

ddev drush cr caused an error message -

```
Warning: Module "PDO" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "pdo_mysql" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I deleted .ddev/php/my-php.ini and restarted ddev. Now ddev drush cr works with no erors.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdo` and `pdo_mysql` are both installed and enabled by default in DDEV, so you don't have to do anything with installing them.

But please note that the database URL you have will be completely wrong. The db host is `db`, so is the user=`db`, pass=`db`, database=`db`. You are trying to set it up as if the db server were on `localhost`, etc.

`ddev describe` will tell you more about your project, and read

https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/database-management/

for a bit more about db management.

Comment: Yes, I was using 'db' for all the creds. I pasted the sample command in Stackoverflow but I was using 'db' in real life.
In case anyone else stumbles on this - I was trying to install civi from the Civi docs which had me composer require civicrm/cv and then cv core:install. This was throwing up the errors about PDO that led me off in the wrong direction.
I cooled off eventually and installed Civi from the Drupal admin gui. It worked first time. Doh.